# Running an asp.net mvc project from a specified area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've an asp.net mvc project with 2 different areas.

[image]

Here is my code in RouteConfig.cs below.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces:new[]{"Sample1.Controllers"}
        );
```

When i run it, i'd like to see the Sample1 as a default project or vice versa. But it gives me an error that i specified below.

```
Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.The request for 'Home' has found the following matching controllers:AreaSample.Areas.Sample1.Controllers.HomeController AreaSample.Areas.Sample2.Controllers.HomeController
```

namespaces i specified doesn't work. Also Sample1AreaRegistration.cs is like that.

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Sample1_default",
            "Sample1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller="Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

How can i solve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't provide Area specific namespace for default route. Instead of having Sample1.Controllers in RouteConfig.cs file, change it to AreaSample.Controllers. And add namespaces in each AreaRegistration files.

- To make Sample1 as default area, I assume, it is a separate project. So try adding it into configuration manager. Select the Sample1 project from solution configuration and run the application.
- Or, try to add specific page as default in project properties. Right click on the project >> properties>> Web>>. Select Specific Page option and type the Areaname/ControllerName/ActionName

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i don't understand your first matter. Also second one doesn't work for me because of deployment. i actually want an area could be a default project when i change the RouteConfig.cs then want deploy with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to not make Sample1 a separate area.  But have Sample1 be the root Controllers/Views for the project (like the default template).

However, if you want to have 2 area like this, then you could probably do something like this:

DO specify the namespaces in the AreaRegistration classes.

Do NOTspecify the namespaces in the RouteConfig.cs class.

In the RouteConfig.cs, you should also provide a default area value.

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Root",
        url: "",
        defaults: new { area = "Sample1", controller = "Home", action = "Index" }

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Comment: In AreaRegistration classes, i put namespaces. Also i changed my code like yours but stil doesn't work.